# What is the use of the | operator in the following command?

Tags: python, c, command-line

In the following command:

```
python -c 'print "A"*20 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"' | ./narnia0
```

What is the use of the `|` operator?

I am a beginner in programming and I wanted to know the role of "|" operator in the above line. I always thought that the operator was a logical operator but the above like makes it look like the operator is used to run the python script in the scanf function of the narnia0 program.

Comment: discussed to death on unix/linux stackexchange

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, please write your titles as short summaries of the problem or question.

Comment: The unix guys might help you with all the details (https://unix.stackexchange.com/). But maybe this is already a good enough start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

the `|` is the pipe operator (Anonymous pipeline).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe):

> In computer science, an anonymous pipe is a simplex
> FIFO communication channel that may be used for one-way interprocess
> communication (IPC). An implementation is often integrated into the
> operating system's file IO subsystem. Typically a parent program opens
> anonymous pipes, and creates a new process that inherits the other
> ends of the pipes, or creates several new processes and arranges them
> in a pipeline.
>
> Full-duplex (two-way) communication normally requires two anonymous
> pipes.
>
> Pipelines are supported in most popular operating systems, from Unix
> and DOS onwards, and are created using the "|" character in many
> shells.

What that means is that the output of the first command, is passed as an argument to the next command after the pipe operator (`|`).

Or more specifically in your example - the output of the Python command is sent as an argument to narnia0.

Pipes are great for passing the output from one command/script to another and makes your life easier.
Lets look at the following example, where we want to base64 encode the content of a file. in that case we could simply do:

```
cat some_file.txt | base64
```

and the final output would be the base64 encoded content of the file that the `cat` command fetched at first and then passed to the `base64` to encode.